# Column can only be numerical or alphanumerical values R

Tags: r, numeric, alphanumeric

Columns can only be numerical or alphanumerical values (i.e. acronym followed by numbers). However, several of these columns have symbols and dates that shouldn't be there. I want the desired output where all values that are not alphanumerical or numerical get flagged as '1'.

i.e.

```
1234           0
ABC1234        0
#              1
12/13/17       1
$              1
ABC            1
```

I am looking for code that isn't specific to the ex data above, rather generalized to apply to several columns.

Edited: Clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to create a logical output which can be coerced to binary

```
+(grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", v1))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1
```

---

If it needs to be a letter followed by number

```
+(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]*\\d+$", v1))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1
```

---

If this is to check every column

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) +(grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", x)))
```

If the intention is to find `any` value that are not alpha numeric in a column

```
v2 <-  sapply(df1, function(x) any(grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", x)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1234, "ABC1234", "#", "12/13/17", "$")
```

Comment: Values that are just alphabetical are also wrong. They need to be an acronym followed by a number or just a number. Will edit for further clarification.

Comment: v1 <- c(1234, "ABC1234", "#", "12/13/17", "$", "ABC")

+(grepl("^[A-Za-z]+\\d+$", v1))

Gives me: 0 1 0 0 0 0
I want: 0 0 1 1 1 1

Comment: @purple_plop i think you haven't used my code correctly `+(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]*\\d+$", v1))#
[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1`

Comment: I have another scenario where I have numbers formatted in this manner: 7.13E + 12    

Thus: v1 <- c(1234, "ABC1234", "#", "12/13/17", "$", "ABC", 1234, 7.13E+12)

As an output I want: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0

How do I format your code to get the above?

Comment: Isn't it `[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0` because `ABC1234` should be 0

Comment: @purple_plop try `+(!grepl("^[A-Za-z]*[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)?$", v1))#
[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0`

Comment: This is for another column that's problematic, I only want numericals for this column. Thank you!

Comment: @purple_plop in that case `+(!grepl("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)?$", v1))#
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0`

Comment: Unfortunately the above code flags 7.13E + 12 too in my work. I don't want it to be flagged, any integer value should not be flagged. Ideas?